# laravel simple axios with argument

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to set axios request but always getting missing argument, but not sure how can I pass it can someone explain why this wont work?

my route: (web.php)

```
Route::post('/api/setSuccessMessage', 'API\SessionsController@setSuccessMessage');
```

my controller: (Controllers/API/SessionsController.php)

```
class SessionsController extends Controller
{
    public static function setSuccessMessage($key, $value)
    {
        session()->put($key ,$value);
    }...
```

and my vueJS axios call (resources/assets/components/Login.vue)

```
created: function () {
            // check is user logged out
            axios.post('/api/setSuccessMessages', {message: 'message',message2: 'message2'}).then((response)=> {
                console.log(response);
            })
        },
```

Comment: Can you give us the names of the files the codes are in instead of `my route` and such?

Comment: @NikolaGavric updated

Comment: Are you using laravel built-in authentication?

Comment: @NikolaGavric no, something custom, but I just need set session message for now just to see how can I pass arguments with axios

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use :

```
 public static function setSuccessMessage(Request $request)
 {
     $key = $request->get('message');
     $value = $request->get('message2');

     session()->put($key ,$value);
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to send the data as a part of your request body you can do so like

```
axios.post('/api/setSuccessMessages', {message: 'message',message2: 'message2'})
     .then((response)=> {
           console.log(response);
      }
)
//you then accept them as such
Route::post('/api/setSuccessMessage/{message}/{message2}', 'API\SessionsController@setSuccessMessage');
```

If you wish to send the data as a request params (everything after ? in the url) you can do so like this

```
 var params = {
    message1: message1,
    message2: message2
 };
 axios.post('/api/setSuccessMessages', {}, {'params': params})
     .then((response)=> {
           console.log(response);
      }
)
//you then accept them as such
Route::post('/api/setSuccessMessage', 'API\SessionsController@setSuccessMessage');
//You can further use them as such in controller
function public test(Request $request) {
   $request->get('message1');
   $request->get('message2');
}
```

I'll reference [axios official docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config) for the axios request params

Comment: nice solution, this second part is more of what I needed, check  vpalade solution its bit cleaner for same result